# Origine de cette tournure de phrase qui utilise le verbe « savoir »

Tags: étymologie, histoire

Dans cette tournure de phrase, le verbe savoir est employé dans une manière différente de son sens normal :

> On ne saura discuter des goûts et des couleurs.
>
> On ne saura être trop prudent.

Je me demande d'où vient cet usage particulier, et de quand date-t-il : latin, ancien français...

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*On ne **saura** discuter/être...* n'est pas idiomatique.

Il s'agit plutôt de *on ne **saurait** discuter/être...*

Cette utilisation du verbe *[savoir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir)* dans le sens de *pouvoir* est très ancienne en français.

Elle est encore présente dans quelques expressions comme celles citées dans la question ou par exemple:

> On ne saurait nier/dire/nier/douter/admettre...

Elles sont toujours à la forme négative et au conditionnel ou au plus-que-parfait du subjonctif.

C'est aussi le sens principal de *savoir* en Belgique, où les contraintes précédentes ne s'appliquent pas :

> Est-ce que tu saurais fermer la fenêtre s'il te plait. (France: est-ce que tu pourrais...)

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/savoir) cite ce vers tiré de « La vie de Saint Alexis », 1050, où savoir est un « équivalent atténué de pouvoir »  :

> *Ne vus sai dire cum il s'en firet liez*

Littéralement:

> Ne vous sais dire comme il s'en avait fait liesse

que l'on peut retranscrire en français contemporain:

> Je ne peux pas vous dire (= les mots me manquent pour vous dire) à quel point il s'en est trouvé heureux.

Si on remonte plus loin. *Savoir* correspond au latin classique *sapere* qui signifiait au sens propre *avoir de la saveur*, puis au sens figuré *avoir du goût, de la sagesse*.

Le texte considéré comme le plus ancien en français, [le serment de Strasbourg](http://www.lexilogos.com/serments_strasbourg.htm), contient le substantif *savoir* mais il est clairement distinct de *pouvoir* :

> *in quant Deus savir et podir me dunat*

c'est à dire :

> autant que Dieu m'en donnera le savoir et le pouvoir

Comment: Sauriez-vous aussi me dire si cette tournure serait aussi naturelle dans la forme interrogative, en plus de la forme négative?

Comment: @Feelew Je ne pense pas. *On ne saurait être trop prudent* donnerait *Saurait-on être trop prudents ?* qui ne me paraît pas préserver le sens particulier de savoir.

Comment: Quelques trouvailles littéraires intéressantes dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* de Robert: 1) un tour interrogatif noté *Vx*, avec un exemple de Racine tiré d’*Andromaque* *«Après ce qu’il a fait, que saurait-il donc faire?»* — 2) Et Baudelaire dans *Le poison*: *«le vin sait revêtir le plus sordide bouge / D’un luxe miraculeux»*, dont l’usage est décrit non comme un régionalisme, mais comme une survivance du français classique pour lequel la distinction entre *savoir* et *pouvoir* était plus floue.

Comment: Je crois que le tour interrogatif, illustré par l’exemple de Racine, survit encore au Québec, mais il semble en effet qu’il ait à peu près disparu de France, si l’on se fie au *Vx* dont on l’a affublé. Il faudrait voir avec d’autres Québécois s’ils approuverent mon jugement...